# Jform POST issues

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api, fix-my-code

I have a form that needs to post to another form (which is an outside form). I have the 1st form set up with the action to the url and method post. However, it is using `JForm`. It is working fine on the 1st form and saving to the database and opening up for editing. However, there is a second action via javascript that POSTs to another page with the new form.

After the page load, I inspect the POST and it shows:

```
Headers   Post    HTML   Cache   Cookies

Parts multipart/form-data

jform[id]   0
jform[state]    1
jform[created_by]   23
jform[grant_type]   A
jform[cycle]    
jform[salutation]   M
jform[first_name]   vrvervtervtgbver
jform[last_name]    rtrgver
jform[title]    rvert
jform[company_name] trvrvetrb
jform[email_address]    trbrtbeb@fgrewgrg.com
```

I can not for the life of me, grab this post data. I have tried everything I can think of using `jinput` and `$_POST`, but nothing seems to work. It either displays `Array(0){[id]=>"" ...` , or `NULL`, or just `ARRAY`. I can not use the Database, for this action as it needs come over via post.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's my code as of right now:

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     1.2.0
 * @package     com_sfinnovate
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2014. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @author      Matt Dray <matt@sooyco.com> - http://www.aespire.com
 */
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet('components/com_sfinnovate/innovatestyle.css');

JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');

//Load admin language file
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_sfinnovate', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JUri::base() . '/components/com_sfinnovate/assets/js/form.js');

if($this->item->id) {
    $canState = JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.state','com_sfinnovate.innofundapp');
} else {
    $canState = JFactory::getUser()->authorise('core.edit.state','com_sfinnovate.innofundapp.'.$this->item->id);
}

$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$fooValues = $jinput->get('jform', NULL, NULL);

var_dump($fooValues);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    getScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', function() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#form-innofundapp').submit(function(event) {

            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="innofundapp-edit front-end-edit">
    <?php if (!empty($this->item->id)): ?>
        <h1>Edit <?php echo $this->item->id; ?></h1>
    <?php else: ?>
        <h1>Add</h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think you need `$jinput->get('jform', NULL, 'ARRAY');`, but I'm not sure I'm following everything...

Comment: No I tried it. it doesn't work.  It seels like it should, but it's not.  I am inspecting it in firebug and I can see the POST data.  It's probably something really simple and i'm just skipping it over.  I don't know what though.

Comment: So I'm not sure that I'm following the actual flow. The form gets submitted the standard way, and you can see the post data in firebug, but then when the form reloads you can't see the post data?

Comment: I can see the post data in the reload as well.  I recieve a POST then a GET and a GET.  the post has all the data in it.  but even when I var_dump ($_post)  all I get is Array().

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not actually understanding where the issue is and what you are asking, I'll be in the chat if you want to go back and forth on this a bit.

Comment: Thanks, but my rep is only 13 and I need a 20.  the issue I have is that in the new form (reloaded page) i can see the POST data in firebug.  the copy above is from firebug  on the very same page where I am var_dump ($_POST) and it gives me Array().  I should be able to get the entire _POST array, into php but i cant.  It will not give me the values. and I don't know why.

Comment: Got it. I'll type up an answer that should hopefully add some clarity to this, though it won't probably solve things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit a form using the standard admin style of Joomla, this will create a POST request to the server. The server will then process the `task` of the form (which is usually 'save' or something similar) to save the form into the database.

At the end of the save, Joomla automatically does a redirect either back to the form view or the list view (depending on whether this was a "save and close" or "save" action). Once this redirect happens, you are no longer in a POST request, but now you are actually in a GET request.

You can check that this has happened by refreshing the resulting page. Did your browser ask you to resubmit form data? If no, then there was a redirect between your post and the response that you ultimately got from the server. Once that redirect happens, no data will be accessible by `$_POST` or any other method on the resulting page.

---

So, if you really need an exact copy of the `$_POST` in the resulting form, your best bet would be to push it into the session during the save process. Then pull from the session instead of from the post data (since that no longer exists).

In the save function, do this:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('post-data', $_POST);
```

Then in your form, you can grab this like this:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$post = $session->get('post-data');

// clear the data so we don't process it again
$session->clear('post-data');
```

Comment: Yea, It's throwing a 500 error with the  
 $session = JFactory::getSesssion();
            $session->set('post-data', $_POST);
WHich seems odd.  Don't know why i'd be getting that.
.

Comment: Got It!!! Thanks!  I used this but bypassed a created form in my component and just placedd it in a custom mod.  Works  thanks.

Comment: Awesome! I fixed the misspelling in `getSession`, which is what was likely causing the 500 error. Only two `s`s in a row...

Comment: Brilliant answer David, showcasing the flow of data when submitting forms. +1

Answer (score 1):

Extending on david's answer. Following technique uses the method that was specifically designed for the problem at hand. The solution is to use `JApplication::setUserState()` and `JApplication::getUserState()` methods. Following code demonstrates the usage

```
//In the save function, do this:
JFactory::getApplication()->setUserState('post-data', $_POST, array());
```

```
//In the form , do this to retrieve the value:
JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('post-data');
```

```
//do following to clear the value
JFactory::getApplication()->setUserState('post-data', null);
```

You can also use `JApplication::getUserStateFromRequest()`. This function **prefers** to load the value from request, and then **saves it in user session as well**. So next time you call this function without having data in request, it'll load the data from session.

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables

I hope it helps someone.